# Return Reference to Structure

Tags: go, structure

I know much People asked that already and I looked into it and tried it, but I don#t get it, first here is my function:

```
func Config() *config {
    configfile := viper.New()
    configfile.SetConfigFile("config.toml")
    configfile.ReadInConfig()
    type configstruct struct {
        first_launch             bool
        generate_desktop_file    bool
        systemwide_desktop_entry bool
        webapps_directory        string
        locale                   string
    }
    config := configstruct{
        first_launch:             configfile.GetBool("general.first_launch"),
        generate_desktop_file:    configfile.GetBool("general.generate_desktop_file"),
        systemwide_desktop_entry: configfile.GetBool("general.systemwide_desktop_entry"),
        webapps_directory:        configfile.GetString("general.webapps_directory"),
        locale:                   configfile.GetString("general.locale")}
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(config))
    return &config
}
```

I tried, to get it to work this way, like many People write it, but then I get this Error, by the `func Config() *config` Line. This is the Error: `undefined: config`. Obviously I did something wrong, but I don't know what I#M doing wrong. And Sidenote, I'm completely new to Go and before I used only Python

I tried to add in to the func the *config and inside the func I added a return &config, I expected that It will return a Pointer that I can use, but I get the Error: `undefinied config`

Comment: You declare your function as `func Config() *config { ... }` which means it returns a pointer to (an address of) a variable of type `config`, but this type is ostensibly not defined anywhere in the same scope as the function, so the compiler hits this place, looks around and reports an error. Please consider _at least_ complering [The tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/) before embarking on Go programming. Python is too different from Go in several respects, so your working knowledge of Python won't help you, quite the opposite, probably.

Answer (score 1):

You should return  `*configstruct` from your function. And its always a good idea to define your struct outside the function ,as otherwise its bound inside the `function` scope ,see the updated code below.

```
type configstruct struct {
    first_launch             bool
    generate_desktop_file    bool
    systemwide_desktop_entry bool
    webapps_directory        string
    locale                   string
}
    
func Config() *configstruct {
    configfile := viper.New()
    configfile.SetConfigFile("config.toml")
    configfile.ReadInConfig()
        
    config := configstruct{
        first_launch:             configfile.GetBool("general.first_launch"),
        generate_desktop_file:    configfile.GetBool("general.generate_desktop_file"),
        systemwide_desktop_entry: configfile.GetBool("general.systemwide_desktop_entry"),
        webapps_directory:        configfile.GetString("general.webapps_directory"),
        locale:                   configfile.GetString("general.locale"),
    }

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(config))
    return &config
}
```